# BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel approxNearestNeighbors function on entire dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to evaluate an entire `DataFrame` through the `approxNearestNeighbors` function of `BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel`

**What I expect:**

A `DataFrame` containing the following information:

```
cookieId    NN
id1         [id3, id5, id7]
id2         [id8, id9]
...
```

Input `DataFrame` (daily_content_transformed):

```
cookieID   features(a sparse vector)
id1        sparse vector with features
id2        sparse vector with features
...
```

**This works:**

```
val key = Vectors.sparse(37599,
  Array(1,4,6,7,16,57,81,104,166,225,290,692,763), 
  Array(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))
model.approxNearestNeighbors(daily_content_transformed, key, 20).show(20, false)
```

It returns a `DataFrame` with 21 rows. I could extract the `cookieId` column from this `DataFrame` and store it in the expected `DataFrame`.

**Where I'm stuck:**

instead of hard coding the key to retrieve NN from, run the method for every row in the input dataframe, and make a dataframe as expected above

Any help?

**Edit in reply to first response:**

After playing around with the suggestion to use `approxSimilarityJoin` instead of `approxNearestNeighbors` I came to the following conclusions:

- the suggested solution works well for `daily_content_transformed.limit(3000)`
- starting from `daily_content_transformed.limit(5000)`, my spark job terminates with an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.
- my input table contains +- 800 000 unique cookieID's (rows).

Although the suggested solution works for small inputs, scalability is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

`BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel` doesn't provide required API. I think you approximate it using `approxSimilarityJoin`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{struct, udf, collect_list. sort_array}

val threshold: Double
val n: Int

def take(n: Int) = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => xs.take(n))

model
  .approxNearestNeighbors(
    daily_content_transformed.alias("left"),
    daily_content_transformed.alias("right"))
  .groupBy($"datasetA.id" as "cookieId")
  // Collect pairs (dist, id)
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"distCol", $"datasetB.id" as "id") as "NN"))
  // Sort by dist, drop dist and take n
  .withColumn("NN" take(n)(sort_array($"NN", false).getItem("id")))
```

This guarantees to preserve at most `n` neighbors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! your solution works well for small dataframes, but is giving problems for my entire ID population